# Handle c++ structures in c#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, arrays

I have a question about handling structs from c++ in c#.

I have a c++ struct, from a third party like:

```
typedef struct 
{
//For application usage, will not access by the core
void* file;         //Application
void* lock;         //Application
void* appParam1;    //Application, maybe filename
unsigned int appParam2;     //Application, maybe length
void* appParam3;    //Application, maybe folder

//Will be used by the core and the hosting application
unsigned char streamMode;       //Read, Write or Append
unsigned int fileOffset;        //Actual file offset
unsigned char buf[DC_STREAM_BUF_SIZE];      //Buffer for reading and writing data
unsigned short bufSize;     //Buffer size, how much is filled from the buffer
unsigned short  bufOffset;      //Offset in reading and writing in the buffer
unsigned char queryData;        //Indicator if actual data are queried

//For internal use only, do not touch
unsigned char requestType;
signed int deviceId;
signed int param1;
unsigned short crc;
void* callback;
unsigned char objType;
void* obj;

} STREAM_HANDLE;
```

In C# this struct is defined as:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential), Serializable]
public class STREAM_HANDLE
{

    public IntPtr file;         
    public object lockobj;      
    public IntPtr appParam1;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U4)] public uint appParam2;
    public IntPtr appParam3;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U1)]public byte streamMode;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U4)]public uint fileOffset;       

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 0x0FFF)]public byte[] buf;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U2)]public ushort bufSize;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U2)]public ushort bufOffset;  
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U1)]public byte queryData;

    //For internal use only, do not touch
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U1)]public byte requestType;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I4)]public int deviceId;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I4)]public int param1;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U2)]public ushort crc;

    public IntPtr callback;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U1)]public byte objType;
    public IntPtr obj;
}
```

I also have in c# an IntPtr to this struct so that i can call c++ functions with this pointer. This works very well.

**Now the problem is that I want to fill the array "buf" from c# so that the c++ function can read it out.
This does not work.**

Here is some more code which I used to create the Handle in C#

```
STREAM_HANDLE Handle = new STREAM_HANDLE
    {
        file = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(name),
        appParam1 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(name),
        buf = new byte[0x0FFF],
        lockobj = new object(),
    };

 IntPtr HandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Handle));
 Marshal.StructureToPtr(Handle, HandlePointer, true);
```

**I have to call some c++ functions with the HandlePointer and i have to modify the content of the "buf" in c#.**

Comment: Any reason why not using Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi as well or what do you need to fill into buf?

Comment: I fill the buffer with byte from a file

Answer (score 0):

The `MarshalAs` Attribute will only ensure that the `buf` field will be marshaled to an inline array when allocated with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`. The C# presentation of that struct has a regular .Net array reference as field. You have allocate and initialize it as usual.
You have to switch back and forth between C# representation and unmanaged handle if you want to use it the way you want.

Another way is to declare it as a `fixed` array. This is only possible in `unsafe` context:

```
unsafe struct InplaceArrayUnsafe
{
    public fixed byte Buf[10];
}

unsafe
{
    InplaceArrayUnsafe a;
    Console.WriteLine(a.Buf[4]);
    Debug.Assert(sizeof(a)); // can even do this
    UnmanagedFunction(&a); // and this
}
```